# Let $L$ be a limit point of a nonempty subset S in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove there exists a sequence of distinct points of S that converges to $L$.

Tags: analysis

${N}'(L, \varepsilon)$ contains infinitely many points of S.

There exists infinitely many $y\in S$ such that $L-\varepsilon<y<L+\varepsilon$

(blank)

There exists infinitely many $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $L-\varepsilon<x_{k}<L+\varepsilon$.

For some $k_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$, For every $k\geq k_{1}$, $L-\varepsilon<x_{k}<L+\varepsilon$, i.e. $x_{k}\in N(L, \varepsilon)$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty }x_{k}=L$.

I think the part (blank) is wrong. How should I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\epsilon = 1$.
Now, $(L-1, L+1)$ contains infinitely many points of S. Pick $x_1 \in (L-1, L+1)$ $\cap \space S$.

Next, set $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Again, pick $x_2 \in ((L-\frac{1}{2}, L+\frac{1}{2})$ \ $\{ x_1\})$ $\cap \space S.$

Set $\epsilon = \frac{1}{3}$. Again, pick $x_3 \in ((L-\frac{1}{3}, L+\frac{1}{3})$ \ $\{ x_1,x_2\})$ $\cap \space S.$

Proceeding like this, we obtain a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of distinct points in S such that
$L - \frac{1}{n} \leq x_n \leq L + \frac{1}{n} \space \forall n \geq1$
which implies $\{x_n\}$ converges to L.

Why the points of $\{x_n\}$ are distinct? Because while choosing every $\{x_k\}$, you're making sure that $\{x_k\}$ is not one of the points you have already chosen, so you just eliminate all the previous points from the interval.